# Python OpenCV - Is it possible to change image dimension / color type of an entire numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv

I am learning machine learning and have successfully attempted at my first CNN. I used 100x100 RGB for it, and the labels + data are saved in an array and pickled so that the order of images is the same for different configurations. I was wondering that, if I want to for example change my image array from 100x100 resolution to 50x50 resolution or turn it to grayscale, what would I have to do, as using cv2.resize and other such commands directly on the array gives errors.

This is the .shape of the array

```
(29700, 100, 100, 3)
```

Comment: Using OpenCV, you need to iterate the NumPy array using a for loop. In some cases, you can use NumPy to apply an operation on a multi-dimensional array (if you really want to). Example for resizing your data using NumPy: `resized_imgs = ((imgs[:, 0::2, 0::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 1::2, 0::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 0::2, 1::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 1::2, 1::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + 4) // 4).astype(np.uint8)` :-)

Comment: For what? For telling you to use a loop or for showing how to use NumPy? I can show you how to convert to Grayscale using NumPy if you want.

Comment: I figured out I had a bug, it should be `resized_imgs = ((imgs[:, 0::2, 0::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 1::2, 0::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 0::2, 1::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + imgs[:, 1::2, 1::2, :].astype(np.uint16) + 2) // 4).astype(np.uint8)`. The `+ 2` at the end is used for rounding, because `round(x/4)` = `floor(x+0.5)` = `floor((x + 2)/4)` and because integer division `x // 4` operation is like `floor(x/4)` when `x` is positive :-)